# Parsing JSON with Python to retrieve values within a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to parse JSON and retrieve a certain value (ID) but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The following is my code and JSON:

```
import json
 
# JSON string
info_symbol = '{"status":{"timestamp":"2023-01-21T15:18:43.937Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":21,"credit_count":1,"notice":null},"data":{"BITCOIN":{"id":15907,"name":"HarryPotterObamaSonic10Inu","symbol":"BITCOIN"}}}'

# Convert string to Python dict
test_dict = json.loads(info_symbol)

print(test_dict['data'])
for name in test_dict['data']['BITCOIN']:
    print(name['id'])
```

Id like to grab solely the ID - so: *15907*

"id":15907,

Comment: Maybe you intended the JSON to have a different shape.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the looping in that case to get only the `id`. If you need all the **key** and **values** from the dictionary then you can iterate like below-

```
import json
 
# JSON string
info_symbol = '{
  "status": {
    "timestamp": "2023-01-21T15:18:43.937Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 21,
    "credit_count": 1,
    "notice": null
  },
  "data": {
    "BITCOIN": {
      "id": 15907,
      "name": "HarryPotterObamaSonic10Inu",
      "symbol": "BITCOIN"
    }
  }
}'

# Convert string to Python dict
test_dict = json.loads(info_symbol)

data = test_dict['data']['BITCOIN']
print(f"only id = {data['id']}")
print("--------")
for key, value in test_dict['data']['BITCOIN'].items():
    print(key, value)
```

## Output

```
only id = 15907
--------
id 15907
name HarryPotterObamaSonic10Inu
symbol BITCOIN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Keys Error**

Fellow, `test_dict['data]['BITCOIN']` is represented as:

```
{
'id': 15907,
'name': 'HarryPotterObamaSonic10Inu',
'symbol': 'BITCOIN'
}
```

Your are iterating the above dictionary, so when you `print(name[id])`, `name` iterator take the key:Value of id, name, and symbol.
Literally tour code is accesing as `id.['id'], name.['id'], symbol.['id]'.`

**SOLUTION**

just access to the id adding one more bracket:

```
print( test_dict['data']['BITCOIN']['id'] )
```

get rid of for loop.